# How to determine the count of Worksheet Tabs that is visible in the Sheet Tab on Excel?

Tags: excel, vba, excel-2010, ui-automation, excel-2007

In Excel, how can I determine which worksheet tabs are currently in view across the bottom of the window (Sheet Tab)? i'm looking for a object property to show if this sheet tab is in view or it is under some other object.

Worksheet.Tab object has no related properties. UIAutomationElement has a property called `.isOffScreen` but it is allways giving false result no matter what the element is visible to user or not.

I tried UIAutomationElement and this is the code example so far.

```
Sub Test()
    Dim AppObj As UIAutomationClient.IUIAutomationElement
    Dim oInvokePattern As UIAutomationClient.IUIAutomationInvokePattern
    Dim oAutomation As New CUIAutomation ' the UI Automation API\
    Dim oPattern As UIAutomationClient.IUIAutomationLegacyIAccessiblePattern
    Dim ouAutomation As New CUIAutomation
    Set AppObj = WalkEnabledElements("Excel")
    Dim ControlName As UIAutomationClient.IUIAutomationCondition
    Dim ControlType As UIAutomationClient.IUIAutomationCondition
    Set ControlName = ouAutomation.CreatePropertyCondition(UIA_NamePropertyId, "Sayfa7")
    Set ControlType = ouAutomation.CreatePropertyCondition(UIA_ControlTypePropertyId, UIA_TabItemControlTypeId)
    Dim testElement As IUIAutomationCondition
    Set testElement = ouAutomation.CreateAndCondition(ControlName, ControlType)
    Set MyElement = AppObj.FindFirst(TreeScope_Descendants, testElement)
    If MyElement Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    Dim isOffscreenProperty As Variant
    Debug.Print MyElement.CurrentIsOffscreen
    Debug.Print MyElement.GetCurrentPropertyValue(UIA_IsOffscreenPropertyId)
End Sub
```

this allways gives me false as a result. i can't figure out if this object is visible (in the view) to user or not.

Comment: Since that all depends on the window size and the status split bar setting, there is no simple/reliable way to do this. Maybe there is a different approach to solving this? Why do you want to know how many tabs are visible? What do you need to do that involves you needing this information?

Comment: yes. i want to make a vba add-in to navigate worsheets without changing activesheet.
For example with ctrl + 6 (numpad) to slide sheet tabs to left. And in this mode press ctrl + 3 to open third worksheet. 
it will be like ctrl+Page Up but without changing the activesheet.

Comment: Given your intention it sounds more like you want to know if a WorkSheet is not "Hidden" or "Very Hidden"
You are also contradicting yourself - do you want to "slide" the sheet left (or right) - the equivalent of the left/right arrows whilst keeping the current sheet Active ("Open") or do you want the equivalent of Ctrl+PageUp - which activates the next sheet.
Also - what if you have 10 WorkSheets - how are you going to make that work?
Better to train users to right click on the sheet navigation arrow to select a sheet from the list

Comment: Does you not wanting to change which sheet is Active have anything to do with some existing code that relies on a specific sheet being active? Changing Excel's UI behavior may be very confusing for users, and you can instead easily qualify your ranges which would make the `ActiveSheet` irrelevant.